# Use setArguments or method for fragment in TABs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make use of the viewpager and the new tab design in android (new being 11+). I see that in the examples, setArgument/getArguments is used to pass info to the Fragment.

I want to pass an object (good size object). I was wondering, why not call a setter instead to avoid serializiation and all that?

For example

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            fragment.setMyCustomInfo(myObject); // method I created to set info
            return fragment;
        }
```

instead of:

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

```
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            fagment.setMyCustomInfo(myObject);
            args.putSerializable("Serial", myObject);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
```

Comment: *why not call a setter instead to avoid serializiation and all that* - because you'll need to take care of calling that setter at the  appropriate times(like after a rotation), the arguments will be always available no matter what configuration change. If the data object is big you could avoid using the arguments by making the fragments retrieve the data from the activity directly(I don't know if this is what you're asking).

Comment: Perfect. Yes how can I retrieve the data from my activity directly? pass a reference to my activity through a setter and retrieve the data from that reference. then we are back to th setter problem.

Comment: Get the reference to the `Activity`(`getActivity()`) and then call some method on it to retrieve the data. This isn't actually a setter, the idea was to avoid making the `Activity` call setters on the fragments(which means finding them first(which is trickier with fragments of the `ViewPager`)). If the fragment manages this part inside you'll make sure that you pass the data when it's actually needed and always to the right fragment.

Comment: Thank you.. add it as answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why not call a setter instead to avoid serializiation and all that?

As I said in my comment, with a setter you'll need to manually call it to pass the data when the `Fragment` is restored(this is kind of the case of a constructor with arguments of a `Fragment` which will not get called in certain situation when the system automatically restores the `Fragment`(this will call the no arguments constructor)). By using `setArguments()` you get this for free and you avoid potential problems.

Another way to approach this is to make the `Fragment` retrieve the data directly from the `Activity`(which will not call any setter). Because you're using the fragments in a `ViewPager` calling a setter will require that you first find the fragments and this could be error prone. If the `Fragment` retrieves the data on its own you'll be updating only the right fragments at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

Large objects in the Fragment arguments will sooner or later fail because there is a certain maximum size that you can have in an intent (I think it's around 1 mB).

Everything that's hard to parcel/serialize or is very large (things holding images for example) should be set via setter. You will have to take care to set the data at the appropriate time. Fragment pagers are especially tricky with this.

Comment: Why do you say appropriate time? I mean if I call a setter to set member variable in that fragment, wouldnt that variable be always there and fragment is always there? Can you ellaborat